# same files only work on a website?

Tags: php, forms

I was asked to check why a particular form is not working. even tho I know nothing about php, I do have a working form that I tested on this website and it didnt work.

I have simply uploaded the same files I have to two different websites. but it doenst work on one of them. its not the code that is incorrect. I have no idea why it only works on a website

edit:
yes I'm afraid they are hosted somewhere else, on different servers

edit: here is the simplified code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>FORM with validation examples</title>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language=javascript>
function valida ()
{


if (document.example.name.value=="")
{
alert ('NAME field is empty!');
return false;
}


else if (document.example.email.value=="")
{
    alert ('EMAIL field is empty!');
    return false;
 }


else
{
return true;
}
}
</script>

</head>
<body>

<form name="example" id="example" action="submit-example.php" method="post" onsubmit="return valida();">    
<fieldset>

<label for="name">Name:</label>
<input type="text" name="name" id="name"/>

<label for="email">Email:</label>
<input type="text" name="email" id="email"/>    

<input type="submit" value="submit" />


</fieldset>
</form> 

</body>
</html>
```

and

```
<?php

$recebename = $_POST['name'];
$recebeemail = $_POST['email'];

$headers = "From: mail@gmail.com\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html; charset=utf-8";

$para = "mail.ccs@gmail.com";

$mensagem   = "<h4>Name:</h4> ";
$mensagem  .= $recebename;

$mensagem  .= "<h4>Email:</h4> ";
$mensagem  .= $recebeemail;

$envia =  mail($para,"E-mail do Site",$mensagem,$headers);

$mensagem2  = "<p>Olá <strong>" . $recebename . "</strong>. Recebemos sua solicitação. Entraremos em contato em breve.</p>";

$mensagem2 .= "<p>Observação - Não é necessário responder esta mensagem.</p>";

$envia =  mail($recebeemail,"Sua mensagem foi recebida!",$mensagem2,$headers);

echo "Mensagens Recebidas com Sucesso!";
echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='2;URL=http://www.google.com.br'>";
?>
```

Comment: More details.  Are these 2 websites on different servers?  Are they on your own servers or hosted somewhere? ETC

Answer (score 0):

Check if there are includes inside the files (like  include 'header.php'; ). If so, you need to correct pathes. Try adding full pathes (/folder1/subfolder/header.php).

Answer (score 0):

I could be several things, first things that come to mind:
Are both servers PHP-capable?
Are the actions on the forms pointing to a separate file?
If so, is the naming correct?
Is the action on the forms a relative or absolute path?
Is there validation on the form that requires a separate js-file?
Is there an ajax function on the form (or on submit)?
...
Are both servers capable of sending e-mail?

Comment: yes its php-capable since the entire website is php. and I dont know if its capable of sending an e-mail but it probably is, since there are other forms on this website and the client never made a complaint about it

Comment: but do those other forms send e-mail?  The thing is that the code looks ok, so the problem probably lies in settings of your server/host or pathproblems.